# Extension to block websites from appearing in search engines?

Tags: website-blocker

I want an extension to block websites from appearing in search engines (not generally). Every link I find about it points me to "Personal Blocklist" by Google but the link to it is broken.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Extension for which software, on which OS? Do you want to block your websites from getting into search indexes – or certain search results from showing up in your searches? In the latter case, what search engines are you using, and with which browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about hiding them when you do a search yourself, you could use the Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey extension to have a script delete them from the results when you do a search.

If you're talking about having them not show up to anyone on the internet and you manage the websites, you can do that via a robots.txt file which you place in the root of the sites.